# Check for continuity and differentiability of $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\cos\frac{x}{n}-1)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a problem I don't know how to approach. I am to check for continuity and differentiability of the given function $f$ : $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\cos\frac{x}{n}-1)$$ and if it is differentiable then I have to check the sign of $f'(0)$.
How to I begin here?

Comment: Note that if $f$ is differentiable at $0$, then $f'(0)=0$ since $f$ is an even function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that the series is convergent for all $x\in\mathbb R$ since
$$\cos\frac{x}{n}-1\sim_\infty -\frac{x^2}{n^2}\quad\forall x\neq0\quad\text{and}\quad f(0)=0$$

The function $g_n:x\mapsto \cos\frac{x}{n}-1$  is differentiable and its derivative is $g_n':x\mapsto -\frac{1}{n}\sin\frac{x}{n}$, moreover in every compact $[a,b]$ we have
$$|-\frac{1}{n}\sin\frac{x}{n}|\leq \frac{|x|}{n^2}\leq \frac{\max(|a|,|b|)}{n^2} $$
so the series $\sum g_n'(x)$ is normal convergent and then it's uniformly convergent in every compact and this is prove that $f$ is differentiable and 
$$f'(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\sin\frac{x}{n}$$
and  especially $f'(0)=0$.